# Is it possible to prevent jumping caret in input to the end when assigning value?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="if(!(event.keyCode>36&&event.keyCode<41)){this.value=check(this.value)}">
```

And action for it:

```
function check(num){
    num=num.replace(/num/g,"Nº");
    return num;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cj4r6/)

The problem is when I assigning value to input the caret jumps to the end. Is it possible to prevent it - I want it to stay where I clicked initially?

Comment: do you want to move cursor at beginnig always when you keyup?

Comment: "...when I assigning value to input" you mean `<input .. value="x" />`? Or you mean when you enter a value into the input-box? Also what's with the `replace(/num/g,"Nº")`? I can still go on. Try to be more specific.

Comment: @akinuri value to this input is being assigned by `num=num.replace(/num/g,"Nº");`

Comment: @nicael Where do you want the cursor to go instead? The fiddle you posted seems to be behave okay for me

Comment: You could try setting the caret position after changing the text http://jsfiddle.net/sjj08q4b/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a JavaScript ninja so I don't know if this is the right way to do this but you could simply update the caret position after replacing the value

In this example, the `check` function takes the input as an argument:

```
function check(num) {
    var selectionStart = num.selectionStart;    
    num.value = num.value.replace(/num/g,"Nº");
    num.selectionStart = selectionStart;
    num.selectionEnd = selectionStart;
}
```

You can see a working example in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjj08q4b/1/)

This may cause strange behaviour if you try to select the whole text using the keyboard (the selection will just disappear). I believe you should make the key code constraints somewhat stricter to avoid that.

Comment: problem with selecting the whole text is not really a problem :D

Comment: `selectionStart` is part of the W3C spec for `input` and `textarea`. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/textFieldSelection.html For other elements you can use the Selection (and Range) API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection